# Data with x and y data, missing data are not taken into account

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = ["2022-02-01","2022-02-02","2022-02-03","2022-02-04","2022-02-05"];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{        
       data: [{x:"2022-02-01",y:16},{x:"2022-02-02",y:16},{x:"2022-02-03",y:9},{x:"2022-02-05",y:11}],
      borderColor: "red",
     label:"data1",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: true
   
  }
  }
});
</script>
```

As you can see there is no data for the date 2022-02-04
but the chart is drawing the next data at this date
Is there away to get the correct chart, except adding the missing data ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this reply will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369556/chartjs-show-gaps-in-time-data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to stick to Chart.js version 2, you should change your x-axis into a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html). Please note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore, you should use the [bundled build](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Also don't define `data.labels` since you provide the data as an array of  data points (objects containing an `x` and `y` property each).

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{        
      data: [{x:"2022-02-01",y:16}, {x:"2022-02-02",y:16}, {x:"2022-02-03",y:9}, {x:"2022-02-05",y:11}],
      borderColor: "red",
      label:"data1",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'D MMM YYYY'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```