# Show missing data points as zero in time series Chart.JS

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a line chart using Chart.js to show requests aggregated by time intervals (15 mins, 1 day and 1 month). There may not be data points for every interval.

Currently Chart.js plots a line joining all the available points. I want to plot all missing points as zero. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand how you identify that a point is *missing*, how do you get its `x` coordinate for which you want `y` to be zero. Can't you make the question more specific by adding maybe some of your code?

Comment: A point is considered missing, when dataset does not contain a value for the time interval. For example, in the following dataset  `{"labels":["10:15","10:45","11:15"],"datasets":[{"values":[100,400,200]}]}`, points `10:30` and `11:00` are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems very similar to this one over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369556/chartjs-show-gaps-in-time-data). I think what you are looking for is something called spanGaps.

Comment: `spanGaps` specifies whether a line should be drawn for missing points. It does not draw the line as zero.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem initially sorry. It is harder to help you now without seeing some source code. I guess your problem is really how do I find missing times in my dataset.

Comment: I have worked around the issue by adding the missing points to the data from PHP. Thanks.